# How to return parameter route from Laravel to Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to return the parameter of a laravel route to an ajax response. This is my

```
public function getPermissions(Request $request)
{
        //$v = request()->route()->parameters('profile');
        $v = request()->route()->parameters();
        return var_dump($v);
}
```

JS:

```
function getPermissions() {
    let data_permissions = '';
    $.post({
        url: '/permisos',
        async: false,
        success: (res) => {
            console.log(res)
        }
});
}
```

This is my route:

```
http://base-laravel.test/profiles/1/edit
```

In the console returns an empty array.
I intend to obtain the 1 that they see on the route. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the **data** to send from Laravel to Ajax Controller. You can pass the data inside the object of the data like

```
$.post({
    url: '/permisos',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        id: '{{$user->id}}' // Suppose you need to pass the user id to the controller
    },
    async: false,
    success: (res) => {
        console.log(res)
    }
});
```

When retrieving the id in the AjaxController, you can simply use the Request $request variable.

```
public function getPermissions(Request $request)
{
    //dd($request->all())
    //dd can be use to die and dump the all variable values 
    return $request->id;
}
```

Viewing in the console, it will display the Ajax Request Id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
$data = $this->route('parameter_to_access');
return $data
```